# Careers 2.0: Profile miscalculates "Currently at" with mixed 4-digit and 2-digit dates

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page, date-format

Test case:

- Add experience at "Current Work Place" during "Aug 10 - Current" (2-digit year)
- Add second experience at "Previous Work Place" during "Aug 2009 - Aug 2010" (4-digit year)

Expected result:

- Profile should read "Currently **Position** at **Current Work Place**"

Actual result:

- Profile reads "Currently **Old Position** at **Previous Work Place**"

Comment: Well, obviously, the year 10 is before the year 2010. `[status-bydesign]`

Comment: `Mathematician` at `Imperial Roman Army, 53rd cohort, Lugdunum Aug 10-Nov 11`